# Magento 1.9 sell online coupon codes

Tags: magento-1.9, module, discount, coupon

I have a Magento 1.9 Store. I want to sell coupon codes as a product name "USD 1000 coupon code". So Customer buy this product then send the order email. This email consist with a unique coupon code which has 1000 USD discount.

This coupon code unique, 1 time use, per customer.

If customer buy 2 qty then send 2 unique coupon codes.

Please help me to sort out this. Appreciate your help.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you want is the principle of `Gift Cards`. Coding it yourself could be a bit time consuming, but there are a few good extensions for this out there.

Comment: Hi "Mayers". Gift card process is worked. Thanks for your idea. Accepted the answer.